# MYSQL Ordering Substring Count

Tags: php, mysql

i want to order my query by counts of the substring.

Table :

id  shop_update

```
1  a,b,c
2  a,b
3  c
4  a,'',c
```

I just to order this by count

```
id  shop_update count
 1   a,b,c       3
 2   a,b         2
 3   c           1
 4   a,'',c      2
```

My query is

```
$this->db->select("*,LENGTH(shop_update) - LENGTH(REPLACE(shop_update,',','')) AS counts");
$this->db->order_by("counts","DESC");
$this->db->from('at_shop');
```

but it returns 0 only in the count

```
 id  shop_update count
     1   a,b,c       0
     2   a,b         0
     3   c           0
     4   a,'',c      0
```

my issue is  `LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(shop_update,',',''),'''',''))`  it was running with space like `LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(shop_update,', ',''),'''',''))`

(spaces are added between (', ')in the query but actual code the spaces are not there)

Please see the difference
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just by using this function in the query will give you the correct count:

`LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(shop_update,',',''),"' '",''))`

See a working example of the same here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa7a5/7

Comment: Is it possible to create these LENGTH and REPLACE functions with HQL ?

Comment: u mean Hibernate QL or Hive QL?

Comment: @Neeks : Sorry for putting in the confusing way. I meant Hibernate QL

Comment: Not much idea about Hibernate QL..check out the docs at http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Answer (score 1):

SELECT *
FROM `tablename`
ORDER BY LENGTH( REPLACE( shop_update, ',', '' ) )  DESC

Answer (score 0):

You may use this command

```
SELECT id,shop_update,LENGTH(replace(shop_update,"''","")) as count FROM table_name ORDER BY  count desc
```